# How to load point on map on change of input value

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, openlayers, angularjs

I am new in OpenLayers. I am trying to map my address location on map by pointing. So I have one input field on change of input field I will get latitude and longitude value and then I will store that value in two global variables that are `globalvar(longitude)`, `globalvar1(latitude)` and access it in my OpenLayers JS file to point location on map.

I am getting value and it also changing on change my input field(suggestion box where I select address and selected address give me lat and log values).

But it is not reflecting on map. not sure but when I enter value in it works

```
geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([4.637777, 50.68728])),
```

When I enter variables it won't

```
geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([globalvar, globalvar1])),
```

This is my JavaScript code:

```
window.abc.prototype.geolocateMap = function(e) {
    ar map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [rasterLayer, vectorLayer],
        target: document.getElementById('map'),
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([2.896372, 44.60240]),
          zoom: 3
        })
      });
    var view = new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
        maxZoom: 16,
        minZoom: 7,
        zoom: 7
    })

    var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
        projection: view.getProjection()
    });
    console.log(globalvar1,globalvar)

    var city= new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([4.637777, 50.68728])),
        name: 'city'
    });
    city.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
            crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
            src: '../../img/abc.png'
        }))
    }));    

    var element = document.getElementById('popup');

    var popup = new ol.Overlay({
        element: element,
        positioning: 'bottom-center',
        stopEvent: false,
        offset: [0, 0]
    });
    map.addOverlay(popup);

    // display popup on click
    map.on('click', function(evt) {
        var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
            function(feature) {
            return feature;
        });
        if (feature) {
            var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
            popup.setPosition(coordinates);
            $(element).popover({
                'placement': 'top',
                'html': true,
                'content': feature.get('name')
            });
            $(element).popover('show');
        } else {
            $(element).popover('destroy');
        }
    });

    new ol.layer.Vector({
        map: map,
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [city]
        })
    })
```

What I found id values are coming but when input get changed the map geom.point method is not loading again.

I am loading my map in idex file like this:

```
<script>new abc('map',{})</script>
```